# Can I render an ERB file to an HTML string inside of a gem (outside of ActionController::Base)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, erb

I am making a gem that will generate a .html file inside of a Rails project's public/ directory. It will be used to automatically generate documentation from Cucumber scenarios.

It would be extremely convenient for me to be able to template the HTML file as ERB, that way I can pass in variables, have ERB do it's thing, then spit out the raw HTML to generate the file from.

I am aware of `ActionController::Base#render_to_string`, but within the gem I am obviously outside the scope of this method. Is there another way to do this? My other option is to define the markup in a heredoc, but I'd rather stay away from that if it's possible to just write ERB files.

Comment: How are you about fake ActionView::Base?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
require 'erb'
ERB.new("Hello <%= 'World'%>").result
```

You could read the template file into a string, render with a new ERB instance and then write your static HTML.

If you need to use variables, you can supply a binding.

```
foo = :bar
ERB.new("Hello <%= foo%>").result(binding) # "Hello bar"
```

[ERB docs](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/erb/rdoc/ERB.html)

[ERB#result](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/erb/rdoc/ERB.html#method-i-result)

Answer (score 3):

Consider using ActionView instead of ERB if you want to access various helpers. Here's a fully working example of how to do this.

```
class MyClass
  def test
    render 'register_user', :jid => 'my login', :password => 'my password'
  end

  private
  def render template, **values
    templates_dir = "#{Rails.root}/app/lib/api"
    template_file = "#{template}.xml.erb"
    ActionView::Base.new(templates_dir).render \
        :file => template_file,
        :locals => values
  end
end
```

A template resides in `app/lib/api` and looks like this:

```
<query xmlns="archipel:xmppserver:users">
  <archipel action="register">
    <%= tag :user, :jid => jid, :password => password %>
  </archipel>
</query>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ActionView::Base.new(Rails.configuration.paths["app/views"].first).render(...)
```